# Knockd not executing the knock command

Tags: arch-linux, security, firewall

I am trying to setup knock daemon, however it does not seem to execute the knock command. To debug the issue, I used this simple configuration, which is slightly edited example from the documentation:

```
[options]
        logfile = /var/log/knockd.log
[openSSH]
        sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/bin/touch /tmp/knock
[closeSSH]
        sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
        seq_timeout = 10
        tcpflags    = syn
        command     = /usr/bin/rm /tmp/knock
```

I can even prove that the knock is detecting the packets sent with `knock -v 192.168.0.2 7000 8000 9000` by running the knockd in non-daemon mode and logging the output as follows `sudo knockd -c /etc/knockd.conf -ienp2s0 -Dv > log`. The contents of `log` file are as follows:

```
config: new section: 'options'
config: log file: /var/log/knockd.log
config: new section: 'openSSH'
config: openSSH: sequence: 7000:tcp,8000:tcp,9000:tcp
config: openSSH: seq_timeout: 10
config: tcp flag: SYN
config: openSSH: start_command: /usr/bin/touch /tmp/knock
config: new section: 'closeSSH'
config: closeSSH: sequence: 9000:tcp,8000:tcp,7000:tcp
config: closeSSH: seq_timeout: 10
config: tcp flag: SYN
config: closeSSH: start_command: /usr/bin/rm /tmp/knock
ethernet interface detected
listening on enp2s0...
-------- snip -------
2024-00-11 13:08:17: tcp: 192.168.0.182:34892 -> 192.168.0.2:7000 74 bytes
2024-00-11 13:08:17: tcp: 192.168.0.182:49042 -> 192.168.0.2:8000 74 bytes
2024-00-11 13:08:17: tcp: 192.168.0.182:47252 -> 192.168.0.2:9000 74 bytes
waiting for child processes...
closing...
```

And no file gets created in `/tmp/knock`. What am I missing?

Comment: cross-posted: https://superuser.com/questions/1825334/knockd-not-executing-the-knock-command

Answer (score 0):

Redirect command output for additional logging.  Modify your commands to redirect output and errors to a file:

```
[openSSH]
sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
seq_timeout = 10
tcpflags    = syn
command     = /bin/touch /tmp/knock 2>/tmp/knock_error
```

```
[closeSSH]
sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
seq_timeout = 10
tcpflags    = syn
command     = /bin/rm /tmp/knock 2>/tmp/knock_error
```

This way, you can check the contents of `/tmp/knock_error`.

If you are using `SELinux` or `AppArmor`, they might be preventing the execution of the commands. Check their logs or temporarily disable.

There's also `dmesg` & `lsof`.

Run `dmesg` after you trigger the knock sequence. Look for any kernel messages, network errors or warnings that could be related to `knockd` or the executed commands.

Use `lsof` and see if there are any processes holding locks on the `/tmp/knock` file. This can help you identify if the file is being created but not removed or for any processes that might be holding the file open.

```
sudo lsof /tmp/knock
```

Look at the system update logs for recent changes that might be an issue.

```
cat /var/log/pacman.log
```

Use `iptables -L -n -v` and check the firewall is allowing the specified knock sequence.

Also, you can verify the process status of `knockd` with: `ps aux | grep knockd`

You can install **Auditd**, or if you have it installed, you can check its logs for audit events.

```
sudo ausearch -m avc -ts recent
```

You can use journalctl to show the most recent logs/details. `journalctl -xe`

Arch Linux may also use `rsyslog`.

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

That's all I can think of at the moment!